# How to copy complete table structure including partitions into another table in oracle?

Tags: oracle, database-partitioning

I need to do exchange partition. I have table_A which is partitioned by File_ID and sub-partitioned by file_type. I need to create temp table within my PL/SQL block which has the table structure as Table_A (including partitions). I need something like below:

```
create table temp_tab as
select * from table_A partition(SYS_P8924) where file_id=1000
partition by file_type
```

I know this a bad code example but somehow Can I achieve this? Appreciate help on this.

Comment: when you create a temp table in Oracle - that table structure lives forever, the data however is generally only there for your session

Answer (score 0):

No worries guys! I got the solution:

```
create table temp_tab
partition by list (file_type)
(
partition values ('P1'),
partition values ('P2')
)
as
select * from table_A partition(SYS_P8924) where file_id=1000
```

Since my sub-partitions were 2 in number, hence it was partitioned into 2 sets.